# How to quickly determine the entry point to a large java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a very large java project, and I was wondering how to quickly determine the "entry point" to this project.  Where, when I run it, is first executed.

Comment: Search for the main( ) function .. as simple as that :)

Comment: What kind of Java project is it? Some types (Android, WAR, etc.) do not have a single point of entry.

Comment: It's not so easy to search for main() when there are upwards of 200 classes :)

Comment: have you heard of grep? Anyway, main() is useful only for standalone applications, webapps do not have one (there you should look for the web-inf files)

Comment: Your IDE should enable you to execute a filtered search exclusively on this project. in this case, filter your search to `static void main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was commented, we need to know what kind of project.  A standalone app will have a main method somewhere, but there are all kinds of different java apps that don't have an explicit one, or for that matter a single entry point.

A project could have several servlets, for example, which all will be started but none is **THE** entry point, they all are entry points to specific functionality.

Many UI projects will also present a series of components to the user, all started by some underlying framework.  Again, there is no entry point, per se, as the main() is actually embedded within the underlying framework.

Comment: This makes sense!  My specific project is a swing project